# Performance metrics for object detection/classification tasks (for images)

Tags: python, image, object, classification, detection

I have a problem calculating evaluation metrics for object detection/classification models.
Let's say a model from Tensorflow Model Zoo is used to train to detect an object and properly evaluated as mentioned in its tutorials on the web.
Here is the problem: i am not sure how to calculate performance metrics, like specificity, sensitivity, F1 score and IOU -that most of them are based on True Positive, False Positive, False Negative and True Negative values- rather than only AP and recall values from standard "coco_detection_metrics".
Tensorboard might be useful for some, but it's not enough, not at all without other metrics for certain tasks.
So, could someone please make this clearer for the community?  Some code scripts would be great for adaptation.

For instance as a step forward: should i add a different metrics_set to "eval_config" to be able to examine metrics i am interested in?

eval_config {
metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
use_moving_averages: false
}
How can i solve this? Oh, Gosh.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the results of your model on evaluation data. Then you can get these results and use them on your own metrics or get metrics from sklearn and apply on your results.

```
# Given val_input, val_y_true as inputs to the model and labels.
y_pred = trainedmodel.predict(val_input)
```

then you can really do whatever you want. For example

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve, auc

precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(val_y_true, y_pred)
auc_trained_model = auc(fpr_keras, tpr_keras)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
plt.plot(precision, recall, label='trainedmodel (area = {:.3f})'.format(auc_trained_model))
plt.xlabel('precision')
plt.ylabel('recall')
plt.title('PR curve')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

This for example would plot the PR-curve of your model.

Comment: I have used Tensorflow Object Detection API, so after training, there is only a file with V2 extension as an evaluation output. If i use the way mentioned in the tutorial, it only gives me mAP. (https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_object_detection_saved_model.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-object-detection-saved-model-py)   So, how can i write the same code in Spyder or PY, i mean, any platform which gives me control on seeing variables like in Matlab. Then, your answer might be useful for a newbie like me God's sake.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: First, it would be useful to provide more detailed information. What is this .v2 you are talking about. What do you mean by evaluation output? Maybe if you provide some code snippets, the problem would be clearer.